# Sorting in SSRS 2008

Tags: sorting, sql, ssrs

I am trying to sort a column from largest value to smallest in SSRS 2008.  These values are derived from an expression, not an actual data field.  So I am wondering if there is a way to sort this column?

This is my expression that is used in this column

```
=fields!Empty_Miles.Value - Fields!Empty_Billed_Miles.Value
```

Comment: I have occasionally encountered what are apparent bugs in SSRS 2008 where the sorting and/or grouping don't work correctly, and I had to simplify the page, just to get it to work correctly.  Thoroughly investigate cases to make sure all data shows up, *then* add the sorting / grouping / etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the whole tablix, right click on the grey border that appears and select tablix properties. Click sorting Add, the click on the expression icon (fx) and enter your expression. For largest to smallest select 'Z to A'. It will sort the whole tablix on this column.